# Regex which controls phone numbers

Tags: php, regex, phone-number

i'm new to regex, and i only need one statement.

I want that my statement accepts these numbertyps:

06643823423 could be longer
or 0664 3843455
or +43664 4356999

and it's important that these is only one statement.

can anyone help me?

Comment: See this post, it forms a good introduction to regular expressions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions

Comment: you need to be way more specific, regex is not something that can be made for a phone number, it needs to have matchable points, characteristics as such, please provide info on specific area codes, mobile / landline ?

Comment: I'd be very wary of using regex with telephone numbers. Most phone numbers have so many different possible working versions it's easy to end up with your validation not accepting real phone numbers. I'd just do a numeric check (with a +()/ check) and max length...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$regExp = '/^([+][4][3]|[0]){1}([0-9]{3})([ ]{0,1})([0-9]{7})$/';
$number = "06643823423";

if(!preg_match($regExp,trim($number)))
{
        echo FALSE;
}
else
{                
        echo TRUE;
}
```

Comment: This (`([+][4][3]|[0]){1}`) hurts my eyes. `(\+43|0)` does the exact same ... and is less confusing, IMO.

Comment: Thanks :) I had used this regEx before 1 month , at that time It is not worked as expected , so I am using like this. now I will use as you suggested

Comment: also, you cant echo false or true haha, there booleans.

Comment: @RobertPitt, you can echo booleans, but it's not pretty.  True prints as '1', and False prints as ''.

Comment: yea you cant echo false is what i meant, why would you want to echo a boolean anyway ?

Comment: @RobertPitt Its just an example , you can do whatever you want to do there. you can return true or false or can do any further process. It was jus texample, haha.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
^\+?[0-9 ]+$
```

You can use that with preg_match, e.g.

```
$matches = preg_match("/^\+?[0-9 ]+$/", $telephone_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

out ofwhat you have there, the only regex I could come up with is:

```
$phone_number = '+449287645367';
var_dump(preg_match("/^[\+|0][0-9]{10,12}$/",str_replace(' ','',$phone_number)));
```

Comment: jensgram, that was not an error mate, it tests for only the + because it can be +[0-9]{12} as well as 0[0-9]{10} the 12 length is to accommodate the +*44*

Comment: So you mean `(\+|0)`, I guess. `[+|0]` means `+` or `|` or `0` AFAIK (I may be wrong, though).

Comment: No your right, for some reason he online PHP tester I used to to test this strips backslashes so after I copied the working regex it had removed the slash :/

Answer (score 0):

Try `\+?\d+\s?\d+`

To explain:
`\+?` - a plus sign (escaped with \, since '+' is a special character in regex). The '?' means '0 or 1 of the preceding characters' making it optional
`\d+` - \d means a digit; the plus sign means 1 or more
`\s?` - \s means a white space character; the ? makes it optional
`\d+` - \d means a digit; the plus sign means 1 or more

So this should match 2 or more digits, with an optional + sign at the beginning, and an optional space somewhere in the middle.